# Делаю GET или POST запрос на сайт bitrix(через node js и c#), выдает не правильную кодировку

Tags: html, битрикс, кодировка

```js
const http = require('http');
const fs = require('fs');



http.get('http://bitrix.loc/', (res) => {
  const { statusCode } = res;
  const contentType = res.headers['content-type'];

  let error;
  // Any 2xx status code signals a successful response but
  // here we're only checking for 200.
  if (statusCode !== 200) {
    error = new Error('Request Failed.\n' +
                      `Status Code: ${statusCode}`);
  } 

  if (error) {
    console.error(error.message);
    // Consume response data to free up memory
    res.resume();
    return;
  }

  res.setEncoding('utf-8');



  res.headers={'Content-Encoding':'windows-1251'};

  console.log(res);

  let rawData = '';
  res.on('data', (chunk) => { rawData += chunk; });
  res.on('end', () => {
    try {
      const parsedData = rawData;   
      console.log(parsedData);

      fs.writeFileSync('gea.txt',parsedData);
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(e.message);
    }
  });
}).on('error', (e) => {
  console.error(`Got error: ${e.message}`);
});
```

Здравствуйте хочу скриптом авторизоваться на сайте битрикса, но есть проблема при получении страницы GET запросом я получаю страницу с непонятной кодировкой, где в html     но русские символы отображаються не правильно, сколько я не пытался менять кодировки через буфер и на сайтах где определить или подобрать кодировку тоже ничего не получаеться

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="ru" lang="ru">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <title>������� �����</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/bitrix/templates/corp_services_orange/favicon.ico" />
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/bitrix/templates/corp_services_orange/common.css" />
    
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1251" />
<meta name="robots" content="index, follow" />
<meta name="keywords" content="����, ������, �������, �������" />
<meta name="description" content="��� ���� - ��� ����������� ������������������� ����,���������� � ���� �������� ���������� �������� ����� � ������ �������� ����������� ���������� � ����������� �������������������." />
<link href="/bitrix/cache/css/s1/corp_services_orange/page_0b4cc56f4ab44347ff9bd583f14d0b95/page_0b4cc56f4ab44347ff9bd583f14d0b95_v1.css?1600068376338" type="text/css"  rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="/bitrix/cache/css/s1/corp_services_orange/template_f01c86e9072d7e85a127fa4d9ad3fed5/template_f01c86e9072d7e85a127fa4d9ad3fed5_v1.css?160006837610369" type="text/css"  data-template-style="true" rel="stylesheet" />
    
    <!--[if lte IE 6]>
    <style type="text/css">
        
        #support-question { 
            background-image: none;
            filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='./images/question.png', sizingMethod = 'crop'); 
        }
        
        #support-question { left: -9px;}
        
        #banner-overlay {
            background-image: none;
            filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='./images/overlay.png', sizingMethod = 'crop');
        }
        
    </style>
    <![endif]-->

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/bitrix/templates/corp_services_orange/colors.css" />
        
</head>
<body>
        <div id="page-wrapper">
        
            <div id="panel"></div>
    
            <div id="header">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td id="logo"><a href="/" title="�� ������� ��������"><img src="/include/bx_default_logo.gif"  /></a></td>
                        <td id="slogan">����� ��� ������� ����� ��������� �����</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>

                
                <div id="search">
                    <div class="flat">
    <form action="/search/index.php">
    <div id="search-button">
            <input type="submit" name="s" id="search-submit-button" value="�����" onfocus="this.blur();">
    </div>
    <div class="search-box"><input type="text" name="q"></div>
    </form>
    </div>              </div>
            </div>


<ul id="top-menu">
            <li><b class="r1"></b><b class="r0"></b><a href="/about/">� ��������</a><b class="r0"></b><b class="r1"></b></li>
        
            <li><b class="r1"></b><b class="r0"></b><a href="/news/">�������</a><b class="r0"></b><b class="r1"></b></li>
        
            <li><b class="r1"></b><b class="r0"></b><a href="/services/">������</a><b class="r0"></b><b class="r1"></b></li>
        
            <li><b class="r1"></b><b class="r0"></b><a href="/contacts/">��������</a><b class="r0"></b><b class="r1"></b></li>
        
</ul>       
                
        
            <div id="content-wrapper">
                <div id="content">
                                    <div id="banner">
                        <div id="banner-image"><img src="/include/banner.png"  /></div>
                        <table cellspacing="0" id="banner-text">
                            <tr>
                                <td width="35%">&nbsp;</td>
                                <td>
                                <big>������� �����?</big>
<span> ������� �� �������� �������� </span>
<small>������� ������ � ��������� ���������� ������ ����� </small>                              </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                        <div id="banner-overlay"></div>
                    </div>
                                    
                    <div id="workarea-wrapper">
                        <div id="left-menu">
                        

<ul class="left-menu">
<li ><a  href="/services/fiz/">��� ������� ���</a><ul><li ><a  href="/services/fiz/cards.php">���������� �����</a><li ><a  href="/services/fiz/credit.php">��������������� ������</a></ul><li ><a  href="/services/smallbusiness/">������ � �������� �������</a><ul><li ><a  href="/services/smallbusiness/credit.php">������������</a><li ><a  href="/services/smallbusiness/leazing.php">������</a><li ><a  href="/services/smallbusiness/deposits.php">��������</a><li ><a  href="/services/smallbusiness/cards.php">����������� �����</a></ul><li ><a  href="/services/corp/">��� ������������� ��������</a><ul><li ><a  href="/services/corp/rko.php">��������-���������� ������������</a><li ><a  href="/services/corp/incass.php">����������</a><li ><a  href="/services/corp/ibank.php">��������-�������</a></ul><li ><a  href="/services/financialorg/">���������� ������������</a><ul><li ><a  href="/services/financialorg/mbank.php">������ �� ������������� �����</a><li ><a  href="/services/financialorg/depservices.php">������������ ������</a><li ><a  href="/services/financialorg/docoper.php">������������� ��������</a></ul></ul>
                        </div>                      
                        <div id="workarea">
                            <div id="workarea-inner">
                            <h5>������� �����</h5> 

<div class="news-list">
        <p class="news-item" id="bx_3218110189_1">
                            <span class="news-date-time">28.05.2010</span>
                                            <a href="/news/1/"><b>���� ��������� ���� ���������� � �������� ������� �� ������ � ����������� ������</b></a><br />
                                        ��������� �������,<br />
�������� ���, ��� ���� ��������� ���� ���������� � �������� ������� �� ������ ��� ����������� ��� � �������������� ���������������� � ����������� ������. � ����� � ���� �� ���� �������� � �������� ����� �������� �������, ������ ����������� ����� � �������������� ���������������� ����� ����������� � ������ ����������� �������. <br />
���������� � ���� �������� ����� �������� ������� ����� �������� �������������.                                 </p>
        <p class="news-item" id="bx_3218110189_2">
                            <span class="news-date-time">27.05.2010</span>
                                            <a href="/news/2/"><b>������ �������� � �������� ���������-������ ����� ��� ����� </b></a><br />
                                        ��� ���� ���������� ����� �������� ������ ��������� ���������-������, ������� ����������� �������� ������ ������ � ��������. ������ ���������� ������� � ��������� ������ ���������, � ��� ��������� ����� ����������� �������������. ��� ������ �� ����� ������� ����� �� �������� �������� ����������, ��� ������� � ������ ������������, ����� ������ �������� � ��������.                                   </p>
        <p class="news-item" id="bx_3218110189_3">
                            <span class="news-date-time">24.05.2010</span>
                                            <a href="/news/3/"><b>������������� ���� ��������� ����� </b></a><br />
                                        � ��������� ����� ����� ����������� �������� ����������� ��� � �������� ��������������� ���������� �����, ������� ���� ������ ���������� �� ���� ����� �������������� ������. ������ ���� ������� ������ �������� ������ �������� ����� � ����� �� ��������� �����. <br />
���� ��������� ����������� ������������ ������������ ���������������� ������������ ������ �� ������� ������������ ��������� �����������. � ����������, ������� ������� � ��������� �������� ������, �� ��������������� ������� ���������� � �� ��������������� � ����������� ��������� �������. ����� ���������� ����� ��������������� � ���������������, ������ ������������ � ��������. <br />
<br />
�������� ���� ��������� �� �������� ������������ ����������.                                    </p>
</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    
                </div>
                
                <div id="sidebar">
                    <div id="sidebar-inner">
                    
                        <div id="telephone"><nobr>8 (495) 212-85-06
</nobr></div>
                        
                        <div id="schedule"><div class="schedule">
                                                    <p>����� ������ �����:</p>
                            <p>������ ���: 10:00 &mdash; 19:00<br />
                            �������: 11:00 &mdash; 17:00</p>
                            <p>����������� &mdash; ��������</p>                 

                        </div></div>
                        
                        <div id="support">
                            <div id="support-question"></div>
                            <b class="r0"></b>
                            <div id="support-text"><a href="/contacts/feedback.php">������� ������</a></div>    
                            <b class="r0"></b>
                        </div>

                    <h5>����� �����������</h5>
<dl class="block-list">
    <dt><a href="/services/corp/ibank.php">��������-�������</a></dt>
    <dd>�������������������, ������� � ���������� ������� �������������� ����������� ������������</dd>
    
    <dt><a href="/services/fiz/credit.php">��������������� ������</a></dt>
    <dd>�� �����, ��� ���� ��� ����� ������ � �� �������� ��� � �� ������ ����� �� ������ ���������</dd>
                            
</dl>   
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    
            <div id="space-for-footer"></div>
            
        </div>
        
        <div id="footer">
        
            <div id="copyright">
            <p>� 2001-2014 ��������� ��������</p>
<p>�����</p>            </div>
            <div id="bottom-menu">          
            
<ul id="footer-links">
    <li><a href="/search/map.php">����� �����</a></li>
    <li><a href="/contacts/">��������</a></li>
    <li><a href="/auth.php">���� �� ����</a></li>
</ul>       
            </div>
        </div>  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: iconv из cp1251 в utf8

Comment: ЅпїЅпїЅпїЅпїЅпїЅ пїЅпїЅпїЅпїЅ,пїЅпїЅпїЅпїЅпїЅпїЅпїЅпїЅпїЅпїЅ пїЅ пїЅпїЅпїЅпїЅ пїЅпїЅпїЅпїЅпїЅпїЅпїЅпїЅ пїЅпїЅпїЅпїЅпїЅпїЅпїЅп, вот это он выдает

Comment: я могу извне обратиться к этому сайту?